# How to navigate to a Type in IntelliJ? or what is the equivalent to Eclipse's Ctrl + Shift + T?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, the "Open Type" dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) allows you to open any type, including those that are in jar dependencies. What's the equivalent for Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is the shortcut you're looking for.

After you hit it, dialog will be shown where you can search through project types, hit that shortcut again and it will include non-project types (dependencies). There is also checkbox for that in the dialog.

The documentation, which includes some tips and tricks for this feature is available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html).

Other alternative is the [search everywhere dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/searching-everywhere.html) (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>). You can search through classes, commands, and a lot of other stuff in this dialog.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (similar to Eclipse <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
For just any file it is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (similar to Eclipse <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> , the action is to navigate/go to class

Answer (score 1):

`Command`-`O` (Navigate > Class from the menu) on Mac.