# How do I view a specific Java source code file from the JDK in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Say I want to open `java.lang.ClassLoader` to see how its methods were implemented.

One method I've found for doing this is by using the `Ctrl+Shift+F` shortcut, changing `Scope` to `All Places`, and typing in the package path above. This will generate a list of classes that reference this package. Clicking a class that uses the package in a field declaration opens up that class, from which I can `Ctrl+left_mouse_click` the class name, which finally takes me to the desired `ClassLoader` class.

Is there a less convoluted way of accessing the class?

I've searched on Google, Stackexchange, the IntelliJ documentation, and looked through the menu bar, but haven't found anything so far. I'm sure this must be documented somewhere, but I may not be using the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Navigate -> Go to class... :

[image]

and then type in ClassLoader to find it (make sure scope is set to 'All Places'):

[image]

The default mapping is `Ctrl + N` (but I'm using the Eclipse keymap, so for me it's mapped to Ctrl+Shift+T)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Here is the detailed response [Navigate to a Type in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159372/how-to-navigate-to-a-type-in-intellij-or-what-is-the-equivalent-to-eclipses-ct)